# For autonomous systems why can't phase trajectories intersect each other?

Tags: classical-mechanics

[image]

According to what I have learned, in an autonomous system the force acting on the particle does not depend on time. In the simplest case we can suppose that force depends only on position coordinate $q$. However, I can't understand why phase trajectory can't cut itself in such a situation (like in the diagram below). Can't $q(t+\Delta t)=q(t)$ and $v(t)=v(t+\Delta t)$ ?

For example in simple harmonic motion where $F=-kq$ the phase trajectory should cut itself because position and velocity do become equal to what they were at some previous time. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It is easy to understand why they don't intersect if we understand that Hamilton's equations have unique solutions and they are deterministic. In the case of harmonic oscillator, the possible trajectories in phase space are ellipses. This means that given a point at instant $t$ in this trajectory, there is a unique point at instant $t-dt$ from which the system has evolved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, the coordinates in phase space are the generalized coordinates $q$ and the generalized momenta $p$, not the generalized velocities $\dot{q}$.  For Lagrangians with kinetic terms more complicated than $(1/2) m \dot{q}^2$, the two are not necessarily proportional.

But to answer your main question: phase-space trajectories certainly can intersect themselves.  As you said, a simple harmonic oscillator just wraps around the same closed curve in phase space over and over again.  But a trajectory can't *cross* itself - that is, you can't have two different curves that meet at a point and then go off in different directions, as you have in your diagram.  That's because for an autonomous system, a system's time evolution is determined entirely by its current location in phase space.  So if you're a given point in phase space, the next place you go is uniquely determined.  Two trajectories that meet at the same point in phase space are completely physically identical at that point, so they can't evolve in two different ways from identical initial conditions.

Another way of seeing this is that for an autonomous system, the time evolution can be visualized by a *single-valued* vector field on the phase space.  So if you're at a point in the phase space, you can only go in the direction pointed to by the vector field at that point.

Comment: +1 you could also explain why some orbits of a pendulum in phase space seem to intersect contrarily to your correct explanation. See the second figure here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_portrait

Comment: @ValterMoretti Good clarification! Phase-space trajectories can appear to cross themselves at unstable fixed points.  In this case the time evolution is actually zero at the crossings - a point exactly at the crossing stays there forever - but infinitesimal perturbations in different directions can lead to different time evolution.  It may be clearer to imagine adding arrows to the diagram - then at any (apparent) crossing, all the arrows point outward, so you still don't have two flow lines truly crossing each other, as in the OP's diagram.

Comment: There are also trajectories entering these intersections. The point is that to reach the intersection takes an infinite amount of time.

Comment: Can you explain why "That's because for an autonomous system, a system's time evolution is determined entirely by its current location in phase space." is true?

Comment: @Blue By definition, a deterministic system's time evolution can only depend on the current state of the system and the time.  An autonomous system is defined to be one whose time evolution does not depend explicitly on time, so it can only depend on the state of the system, which is by definition given by its location in phase space.  If its location in phase space *doesn't* capture all the relevant physical information about the system, then you need to expand your phase space so that it does.

Comment: Quick sidenote: some people/textbooks/authors actually do refer to both p vs q space AND q-dot vs q space as "phase space." See e.g. Ralph Baierlein's "Newtonian Dynamics" and this intermediate mechanics teaching tool: https://faculty.gvsu.edu/ambroseb/research/IMT-Osc3PhsSpc.html 
In fact, John R. Taylor's Classical Mechanics actually acknowledges this as a possibility too.